# Trigger created with compilation error:

Tags: triggers

i am getting compilation error each time i tried to create a trigger: please find below problem statement and code:

problem Statement:
Create a trigger named 'trigger_credit_bf_update' that is triggered whenever the credit_card table is updated. This trigger will insert the cc_type and action into the table 'credit_card_log_history' before the updation of credit_card details. The action name in the affected log table credit_card_log_history is 'Before_Update_Credit_Card':
my code link this for question:

Code:
create or replace trigger trigger_credit_bf_update
before update on credit_card
for each row;
BEGIN
insert into credit_card_log_history (cc_type, action)
values (:old.cc_type, 'Before_Update_Credit_Card');
END;

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  trigger_credit_bf_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON credit_card 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO credit_card_log_history (cc_type, action) Values 
(:old.cc_type, 'Before_Update_Credit_Card');
END;
```